# How to convert sql query to hibernate query for get last week records from database

Tags: mysql, hibernate

In my project i want to get the last week records inserted records based createdtimestamp and product type. I have added both sql and hibernate queries below.In this the sql query works fine, but hibernate query giving error.. Please help me how to convert sql query into hibernate query.

select * from products where createdtime BETWEEN DATE_SUB(now(),INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND now() and  p.producttype=? order by createdtime desc;

from products as p where p.createdtime BETWEEN date_sub(now(),interval 7 day) and now() and p.producttype=? order by p.createdtime desc

> ERROR: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter - line 1:118:
>   unexpected token: interval ERROR:
>   org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter - line 1:118: unexpected
>   token: interval line 1:118: unexpected token: interval    at
>   org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.identPrimaryBase(HqlBaseParser.java:4648)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try this ..

This way you can also try..

```
   final Calendar date = Calendar.getInstance();
    date.add(Calendar.DATE, -7);
    Date previousDate=date.getTime();
    Date now=new Date();

session.createQuery("from products as p where p.createdtime BETWEEN "+previousDate+ " and "+now+ " and p.producttype=? order by p.createdtime desc")
```

Comment: Thanks for your response Gokul.I have tried with your given code but still i have face below error.ERROR: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter - line 1:118: unexpected token: Mon
ERROR: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter - line 1:118: unexpected token: Mon
line 1:118: unexpected token: Mon